# Copy text from Word and get file location from clipboard

Tags: c#, windows, clipboard

I want to achieve the following:

I copy some text in a Word application (or another application where the clipboard is updated with text). I now want to know the location path of the Word document, so I can store the path and open the document for a reference later on.

I would like to do it for websites as well, so I can get the website where the text was copied from.

I want do this in C# and Windows 10. My initial thought was to create a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> event listener, and find the active application and get the location like that. But I cant link the copied text, and the text path together.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve such information, but with limitaions. When there is no such information stored in clipboard you're out of luck, but, hopefully for you, many applications store way more data in clipboard along with text, including path or url to the document.

Different applications using different different formats to track document location, so main idea is to try read from clipboard all relevant clipboard formats that include document location one by one and try to extract location.

Here several clipboard formats that contains or can contain information needed to you:

- [HTML Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa767917.aspx)
- msSourceUrl
- [FileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776902.aspx#CFSTR_FILENAME) and FileNameW
- [UniformResourceLocator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776902.aspx#CFSTR_INETURL) and UniformResourceLocatorW
- ObjectLink
- [Hyperlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767974.aspx)
- etc.

You can find more about different clipboard formats [here](https://www.codeproject.com/reference/1091137/windows-clipboard-formats). Also you can use any [clipboard format viewer](http://www.freeclipboardviewer.com/) to view what is actually stored in clipboard by different applications.

For example, **all** modern browsers and **all** Microsoft Office suite applications store in clipboard actual document location in `HTML Format` as simple plain text:

```
Version:1.0
StartHTML:000000271
EndHTML:000008359
StartFragment:000008219
EndFragment:000008255
StartSelection:000008219
EndSelection:000008255
SourceURL:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672385/copy-text-from-word-and-get-file-location-from-clipboard-c-sharp
...
```

Comment: Great!  I tested it and information is indeed there.  Only it should be noted that the slashes are inverted and symbols are escaped as in a URL:
SourceURL:c:/Documents/Some%20Document.docx

Comment: Looks like there are some really good possibilities there! So instead of clipboard.gettext(), the source will be stored as html instead. Nick, can a see how you did it? Thank you so much for you answer!

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what i was looking for! Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Html);

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, I am afraid.  This information is not made available in the clipboard.

Even if you listen to Ctrl + C and find an active instance of Word running, you still won't be 100% you get what you need.  It might be a new document, which is not even saved yet on disk.  Even more convoluted case: the user copies some text from an edit field on a dialog in Word.

Comment: "This information is not made available in the clipboard" that's not what he's asking. He wants to put something on the clipboard, which is possible only not what he wants.

Comment: No i get i cant do it through the windows clipboard. But ive seen a application like http://www.aiclipboard.com/, where they do manage to get the path. Do you have any idea on how they have done it I.E see link?